# PropertyGrid PropertyValueChanged PropertyInfo is Nothing (.NET 4.0 )

Tags: vb.net

OK. I am trying to cancel or revert the change from a PropertyValueChanged event. I have determined that the PropertyInfo is Nothing for some reason. Here is the entire code. Any ideas as to why the PropertyInfo would return Nothing?

```
Private Sub pgSetup_PropertyValueChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PropertyValueChangedEventArgs) Handles pgSetup.PropertyValueChanged

Dim iChangedItem = e.ChangedItem
Dim propertyName = iChangedItem.PropertyDescriptor.Name
Dim pInfo As PropertyInfo = pgSetup.SelectedObject.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)

pInfo.SetValue(pgSetup.SelectedObject, e.OldValue, Nothing)

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be great if you could tell us what type `pgSetup.SelectedObject.GetType()` yields and the value of `propertyName` when you encounter the problem.  Be advised that a type can yield a PropertyDescriptor instance even though no such property actually exists on the type.  Also, the `PropertyDescriptor` exposes a `SetValue` method similar to the one on `PropertyInfo`.

Comment: GetType() returns {Name='Boolean" FullName = "System.Boolean"} so I think it's returning the correct type. I have tried the PropertyDescriptor.SetValue as well, but again since it requires a valid PropertyInfo, I get the same results as using the PropertyInfo SetValue

Answer (score 0):

With the help from a user in another Forum, this is the solution that ended up working:

```
Dim propertyName = e.ChangedItem.PropertyDescriptor.Name
Dim pInfo As PropertyInfo = pgSetup.SelectedGridItem.Parent.Value.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)

pInfo.SetValue(pgSetup.SelectedGridItem.Parent.Value, e.OldValue, Nothing)
```